# Database Instant File Initialization For Microsoft Sql Server Local DB 2016 SP1

Tags: sql-server, testing, localdb, sql-server-2016-localdb

My company makes extensive use of Microsoft SQL Server Express Local DB 2016 (SP1) for code testing. I recently read about Database Instant File Initialization, and I believe this would improve the performance of our testing processes.

When I check the logs for the Local DB instance, they indicate that Database Instant File Initialization is disabled. I have made sure that my specific user has "Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks" permissions.

Does anyone know if this feature works in the Local DB version? If so, any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: What led you to believe that IFI would improve testing processes? What specifically needs improving?

Comment: I appreciate the response and desire to dig deeper, but I am really looking for an answer to my question versus debating the merits of the feature in my use case.

Comment: I would not think that it is applicable to localdb as localdb is nothing more than a detached database on disk. This seems to be able to create and attach a db on sql server and 0 the reserved space for the data files.

Comment: Have you tried creating an empty data file and use that as the "starting point" for your tests? (So just create a copy of it every time you need a new database in any test(s).)

Comment: Igor, thank you for your response. From everything I have ever seen, Local DB is behaves just like any other SQL Server Express instance. I am pretty sure at one time, when the product was known as Compact Edition, this was not true. I can see why you would say that it is “nothing more than a detached database” about Compact Edition, but to me that is not true with Local DB. The fact that I can see in the logs that it is disabled tell me that it is possible in this edition, but for some reason it is either not working or not being allowed to work.

Comment: Igor, to your second question, I would say that I appreciate your desire to help me find other methods of achieving a similar result to Instant Database Initialization. But what I am really interested in is the answer to my question as to whether or not Instant Database Initialization is possible in Local DB, and if so what I might be doing wrong.